# Trigonometry Addition Thereom With Only one exact value?

Tags: trigonometry

Use the expression of $\sin(A+B)$ to evaluate $\sin 195$.

Do I use one exact value like $45+150$ or $60$ or is there another way?

Comment: 45 and 150 look fine

Comment: Given that $150=180-30$, it should be easy.

Comment: so i just try and simplify as much as possible. Considering i can't use any other exact value to add up to 195?

Comment: just try to use combination of known angles value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: $\sin 195° = -\sin 15° = -\sin(45-30)°$. After that you use standard formulas.

Comment: Oh okay thank you ! very helpful!

Comment: One last question ? since in 3rd quadrant (TAN) would i add a negative symbol to the final answer?

Comment: all necessary signs are already included in my formula and in the formula for sinus of a difference. For self-control, check that final result is negative. You can always check it online, say, at wolframalpha.com

Comment: @MATHSUSER: Notice that *The negative* in $\sin$ is cause of that. So, need not add any signs again.